# Summation of tensors and weights changing dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to create a custom layer in keras, but I'm coming across a strange issue. When I'm summing the tensors before returning the answer, the dimensions change. This happens when I sum the bias weights to the two tensors, see the code below.

```
    summation = tf.math.add(biTensorVector, normalTensorVector)

    print('summation1 ',summation)

    summation = tf.math.add(summation,self.b)

    print('summation2 ',summation)
```

which gives

```
summation1  Tensor("sequential/ntn/Add:0", shape=(5, None), dtype=float32)
summation2 Tensor("sequential/ntn/Add_1:0", shape=(5, 5), dtype=float32)
```

which surely should give an output shape (5,None)?

`self.b` is initialised with:

```
self.b = self.add_weight(name='b',shape=(self.k,),
                                  initializer='zeros',
                              trainable=True)
```

Shouldn't the weight `self.b` broadcast to be the shape `(5,None)` then added to the summation, rather than removing the `None` dimension? Any clarification would be much appreciated.

The `None` size is from the initialisation of the layer, supposedly if it works with `None` it ought to work with any number of samples I assume? Hence why I'm quite confused.

I should add I have just tried the `+` operator and I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shapes of `biTensorVector`, `normalTensorVector` are probably (5, None). So adding them gives (5, None) because the second dimension is unknown.

Shape of `self.b` is (None, 5). Adding (5, None) and (None, 5) always get (5, 5) (or error). So keras knows that the result of the second addition is (5, 5).

Comment: The shape of `self.b` is declared as (5, ), so I don't understand what you mean, sorry? You're right about the dimensions of the previous two tensors. I thought adding a (5, ) tensor to a (5, None) would preserve the dimensions? I also am unable to tile `self.b` because of the `None` dimension.

Comment: @Adsmeach as far as I understand keras adds batch dimension automatically

Comment: Issue fixed, I took the transpose of  the first `summation` and that preserved the dimensions. Can't say I understand why (since self.b dimensions did align with summation before the transpose) but I'm glad it's working now. Thanks for your help!